# Why are several of my comments being deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

I had a comment [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84193/why-is-discussion-of-the-israel-lobby-so-taboo-in-the-united-states) replying to another user which was removed. I've noticed this happening on numerous threads now, where my comments are being removed from controversial threads.

I can understand why moderators want to avoid excessive discussion in the comments in controversial topics like Israel-Palestine. We don't want this website to be another Reddit. However, it is concerning when my comments are deleted but not those of my debate adversary who holds the opposing view. It gives the impression that the moderators or whoever is responsible for deleting comments has a bias.

I also note that this deletion tends happens in debates with "power users" i.e., folks with extensive karma on this and other SE websites or moderators on other platforms. This gives the impression to me that "powerful" users are exploiting said power by removing comments they personally dislike or which criticize their writing.

Comment: It is hard to answer without knowing what the comments are as there are many different reasons for them to be removed.

Comment: The moderators know this and can see even the deleted comments.

Comment: A couple of things: 1. I flagged the comment where you had a thinly veiled accusation of racism aimed at me. 2. I carry no more weight around here than you do. I can talk to Politics.SE mods in backchannels, but I really don't do so about moderation stuff (and I did not here)

Comment: Cannot say anything about this particular isntance, but sadly, I have been noticing similar. Any content seen to be pro-Palestinian is quickly closed / edited / deleted. This is a trend across [tech and social media](https://theintercept.com/2024/01/10/israel-disinformation-social-media-iron-truth/)

Comment: *"my comments are deleted but not those of my debate adversary who holds the opposing view"* - so, what I see here is 1. You are trying to debate in comments, they absolutely should be deleted, and 2. You are not using flags, they are the only appropriate response to comments which 'hold views' in any political sense, as they are evidently not purposed to improving the post, and absolutely should be deleted.